# Event listener added on click but runs straight away?

Tags: javascript

I add an event on click of my button:

```
this.$refs.btn.addEventListener('click', this.turnOn);
```

In the `turnOn` method I add a listener on the document, to run the `turnOff` method.

```
turnOn() {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.turnOff);
}
```

Then during testing, I click the button and the `turnOn` method runs, but that initial click also runs the document click listener.

How can I run the `turnOn` method, add the document listener, but not run the document click listener on the initial button click?

Comment: you are adding 2 `addEventListener`?

Comment: 2 event listeners for 2 different elements.

Comment: do you mind explaining what you have and what you want to do

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is due to event bubbling.When you click on `<button>` an eventListener is attached to body and after that due bubbling its called.
 You can prevent that using `event.stopPropgation()`. Below are two snippets to see the difference.

### Non-Working

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
  document.addEventListener('click',()=>console.log("body clicked"));
  console.log("button clicked")
})
```

```html
<body>
<button>Test</button>
</body>
```

**Note**: The above non-working example also adds multiple click events on each click on Test

### Working

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
  e.stopPropagation();
  document.addEventListener('click',()=>console.log("body clicked"));
  console.log("button clicked")
})
```

```html
<body>
<button>Test</button>
</body>
```